# How to add a jQuery Tooltip feature on JQuery.awesomeCloud.plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, word-cloud

I'm trying to implement a jQuery Tooltip whenever I mouseOver a certain word in the wordcloud. 
The wordcloud references I'm using is [jQuery.awesomeCloud.plugin]:https://github.com/indyarmy/jQuery.awesomeCloud.plugin

Or is there any other way to add a tooltip hover over a word in using this jQuery wordcloud?
Please assist me.

Thank You.

My codes as follows:

```
<!--jQuery ToolTip-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
<!--Calling Tooltip function in jQuery-->
$(function() {
$("#age").tooltip();
});
<!--End-->
</script>
<!--End-->
  <!--WordCLoud References-->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>//Conflict with jQuery script above-->
<script src="jquery.awesomeCloud-0.2.min.js"></script>
<!--End-->       
   <div class="content">
  <div id="wordcloud2" class="wordcloud">
    <span id="age" data-weight="90"><a href="http://google.com" title="CAN YOU SEE ME">google</a></span>
</div>
```

I think is this one preventing me to pop out this tooltip

```
  $("#wordcloud2").awesomeCloud({
    "size" : {
        "grid" : 9,
        "factor" : 1
    },
    "options" : {
        "color" : "random-dark",
        "rotationRatio" : 0.35
    },
    "font" : "Impact",
    "shape" : "square"
});
```

Comment: Hi @DainisAbols thank you for taking time to answer. Yes. I did this way but apparently there is no text when hover over. I have been cracking my brain with it.I think it might be the jQuery.awesomeCloud problem. This jQuery is using DOM addeventlistener. Is this the reason that's affecting my codes from appearing ? :/

Comment: Try checking the jQuery script for signs of title manipulation.

Comment: Hi @DainisAbols , nope couldn't find it.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. Will need to see more code, to help you with it.

Comment: Hi @DainisAbols Inserted the codes as follows :)

Comment: Added your code: http://i.imgur.com/dR8PQ95.png I can see the title just fine ... if you can't see the title, then there is something else wrong with your code.

Comment: Hi @DainisAbols I believe you haven't references the wordcloud jQuery to output this word "google" right?

Comment: Yes, I do: http://i.imgur.com/AUJhY7T.png :) But I don't have any custom CSS set for that.

Comment: Hi @DainisAbols, I'm so sorry. I think its this script code.

Comment: @DainisAbols I think is the calling of this javascript is creating the trouble. I listed the function on top. That function inserted it inside the body tag. Mind taking a look again ? :>

Answer (score 1):

tryied with your code, it is working fine.
     
     
     
      google

```
   $(function() {
    $("#age").tooltip();
   });

  fiddle url:  http://jsfiddle.net/7GvQt/
```